# Angular - .Net Core Application - Okta Setup Question

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, okta

I have an application that is a SPA angular application connecting to an ASP.Net Core API service side.  First question I have is where should the Okta authentication happen at the Angular client side or the service side with the client id and secret key?

The other thing is can SAML be used in the sense that if the user is authenticated already can that be passed on via SAML where the user is not prompted for credentials?

Answer (score 1):

Always authenticate on the server. Everything on the client-side can be read. Majority of apps with this setup pass a token with each request, which is validated/verified on your .net core side.

A simple flow is:
User enters credentials -> POST to server where it's validated -> Server returns token -> Tokens stored in local storage and passed in each subsequent request when the API is hit.

Look into Guards in Angular which'll help hold down your front-end, while the server side will work if a valid token is within the request.

Here's an additional link that may be helpful:
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/04/26/build-crud-app-aspnetcore-angular